# FUA, flush and ordering

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, nvm

A `FUA` command usually means the data needs to be committed to the `NVM` before signalling completion.

From my understanding, there is no requirement to flush the data before the `FUA` command to the `NVM`.

1.
If we have 
LBA0 (*in Cache*), LBA1(*cache*), LBA0 with FUA,

Can LBA0 with FUA complete first and then LBA0 in Cache complete? 
Is there an ordering requirement for the two ?

2.
Again if we have commands:

```
Write LBA0 with X

Write LBA1 with Y

Write LBA0 with Z and FUA is set. 

READ LBA0
```

Can Read of `LBA0` return X or Z?

---

3.
**Another question** is about the `FLUSH` :

If `flush` comes with a data :

the data in write cache must be committed before the `BIO` that is flagged with Flush gets executed.

if a `FS` issues:

```
WRITE LBA0 with X (1) 

FLUSH

WRITE LBA0 with Y (2)
```

if (2) is issued after `FLUSH` completes, the ordering is guaranteed.
However, if (2) is issued before `FLUSH` completes , so both are in flight commands, can (2) complete before `FLUSH` ?

Comment: It's a good question. I think if it's not defined in protocol it would be storage firmware specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that the current state of Linux kernel handling of block I/O barriers is described by https://lwn.net/Articles/400541/

That is, queued requests (whether in software or hardware (NCQ, TCQ)) are generally unordered, and the kernel or hardware is free to process them in any order. If there is a need for ordering, higher levels (e.g. the filesystem) is responsible for waiting for completion.

Say, if a file system wants writes A, B, C to be on disk before writing a journal commit record X, it must do something like

1. submit A, B, C
2. wait for A, B, C to complete
3. Issue FLUSH (which makes sure that A, B, C go from the disk cache to persistent storage)
4. Write X with FUA bit set

   - Alternatively, if the HW doesn't support FUA, this can be emulated by

     4. Write X
     5. Wait for X to complete
     6. Issue FLUSH

Now, for your questions:

1. No, there is no ordering requirement.
2. Unspecified.
3. I'm not sure, but I believe FLUSH is unordered, just like other commands.

Comment: Thank you, This is my understanding too at the minute. Can I also say the following : If a FLUSH comes with Data: then this data must be sent after the flush. So there is some sort of lose ordering there?